# Meaning of the unique up to a normalization factor

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

In the following text about Gaussian quadrature by Brian Bradie I cannot understand the meaning of the author:

> Associated with each weight function is a special family of
>   polynomials, unique up to a normalization factor.

What is the meaning of the *unique up to a normalization factor*? There are [books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22unique%20up%20to%20a%20normalization%20factor%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) with the same statement (i.e. unique up to a normalization factor) in other topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it means "unique up to a re-scaling of the independent variable." For example, $x^2+x+1$ is essentially the same thing as $4x^2+2x+1$ under the transformation $x \mapsto 2x$.

The idea is that we can arbitrarily re-scale our domain to make life more convenient, for instance changing a length scale from meters to kilometers, or choosing a scaling of an orthogonal polynomial family such that $\langle P_i P_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you. But what about $x^2+x+1$ and $4x^2+4x+4$? Can I replace $4x^2+4x+4$ instead of $4x^2+2x+1$ in your example with defining $p(x) \mapsto 4p(x)$?

Comment: That scaling changes the range of the polynomial, not the domain. You can do that, but you should be more careful.